# I am getting a runtime error in this code written in java. Kindly check the mistake ill send the error too

Tags: java

```
/* package codechef; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*; import java.lang.*; import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */ 
class Codechef {    
   public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception   {
        int x=0,y=0,b,z=0,ctr=0,c;
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));      String s = buf.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter No. of Test cases");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(s);
        int arr[] = new int[a];
        if(a>=1 && a<=1000)
        {
         for (x=0;x<=a-1;x--)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the cases");
            arr[x]=Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
        }
        for(y=0;y<a;y++)
        {
            if(arr[y]>=1 &&arr[y]<=1000000 )
            {
                c= arr[y];
                b=a*2;
                for(z=1;z<a;z++)
                {
                    if(z==1||z==2||z==a)
                    {
                        if(b%z==0)
                        {
                            ctr++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(b%z==0)
                        {
                            ctr++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(ctr>3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Sorry");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("lucky Number");
                    }
                }
             }
         }    }
    }
```

Comment: What error? Where? Please give us some text describing the details of your problem. Please look at the [help] as well as [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how you can improve this question and increase your odds of getting decent answers.

Comment: Can you please add the exception you get to the question body?

Comment: thank you Guys!! I gt the solution

Comment: I am really sorry it was my first time will take care next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few issues. Not sure what you are trying to do with this, but first thing I noticed is that you probably want to put your `System.out.println` before you read from `System.in`.

As you have it written, it will wait for the user to enter a number without prompting for it. Move `System.out.println("Enter No. of Test cases");` above the `BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` line. That way it will prompt for the number of test cases before reading it from `System.in`.

The next thing I notice is that your indexing on the first inner `for` loop is wrong, which is resulting in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception. In your first `for` loop, on the inner loop you have `for(x=0;x<=a-1;x--)`. You are decrementing your index variable `x` where you want to increment it. Changing that inner for loop to `for(x=0;x<=a-1;x++)` will get rid of the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.

As for the rest of your code, I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but it executes without error once you fix the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.